# How to get post info, when user visits a post page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

When a user visits a particular post or page ( except home page ) how to get the post info ( atleast ID of the post ) in php? which action or filter best suits for this ?

I want to detect when a user visits a page or post and make an html log like this:

`a user visited the page <a href="link_to_post"> Post Title </a>`

i currently have `the_post` action but it runs in home page also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_home()` to check if it's home page or not. And you can use `get_permalink` and `get_the_title` to get link and post title

Try this:

```
if (!is_home()) {
    echo 'a user visited the page <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
}
```